# Função do Redux Saga não está sendo chamada

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Estou tendo um problema com o Redux Saga. A requisição está chegando na action e no reducer mas não passa pelo Saga. Estou iniciando no Saga então não estou conseguindo identificar qual é o problema

**Action:**

```
export const login = (data) => ({ type: 'LOGIN', data })
```

**Reducer:**

```
export default function login(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {   
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'LOGIN':         
         return {...state, loading: true};
      case 'SUCCESS_LOGIN':                  
         return {...state, data: action.data, loading: false, error: false};
      case 'FAILURE_LOGIN': 
         return {data: {}, loading: false, error: true};
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
```

**Saga:**

```
import { takeEvery, put, takeLatest, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import AXIOS from '../../config/axios';

async function apiLogin(data) {
   const response = await AXIOS.post('/login', data);
   localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

   return response;
}

function* asyncLogin() {   
   try {
      const response = yield call(apiLogin)

      yield put({ type: 'SUCCESS_LOGIN', payload: { data: response } })
   } catch( err ) {
      yield put({ type: 'FAILURE_LOGIN' });
      console.log(err)
   }
}

export default function* root() {      
   yield [
      takeLatest('LOGIN', asyncLogin)
   ];
}
```

**Store:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import { Reducers } from '../reducer';
import rootSaga from '../saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando o "all" antes da chamada.

yield all[
      takeLatest('LOGIN', asyncLogin)
   ];

Espero que ajude :)